# Asymptotics of integral of exponential

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, asymptotics

I'm looking for references/an answer to the question of the asymptotics as $\kappa \rightarrow \infty$ of the integral
$$\int_L^\infty t^{m-1} e^{-P(t, \kappa)}dt$$
where $P$ is a polynomial and $\kappa$ is a parameter. I'm not sure where to start/if there is any easy answer. One point is that of course we need the highest order term in $t$ to have a positive coefficient (otherwise for any $\kappa \geq 0$ the integral diverges), so I guess the answer can include some assumptions on the polynomial $P$, although it would be nice if the answer exists for a general polynomial of the form
$$P(t, \kappa) = t^nQ(\kappa) + R(t, \kappa)$$ where $m \geq 0$ and $R(t, \kappa)$ is a polynomial of order at most $n-1$ in $t$. (I guess for simplicity $Q(\kappa) \equiv 1$ is also of interest.) $L$ can be anything - I've included it if it makes the answer somehow simpler (e.g. if $L = 1$), and $m$ is there so that the integral mimics the Gamma function somewhat (although I'm not sure if it helps).

Here is an example: if $L = 0$, $m = 3$, and $P(t, \kappa) = t^4 - \kappa t^2$, then Mathematica gives
$$\int_0^\infty t^3e^{-(t^4 - \kappa t^2)}dt = \frac{1}{8}\left(2 + \kappa e^{\kappa^2/4}\sqrt{\pi}(1 + \text{erfc}(\kappa/2))\right)$$
so the asymptotics should be $\kappa e^{\kappa^2/4}$ modulo constants since $\text{erfc}(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Is there a way to obtain asymptotics for integrals that might not necessarily admit a closed form?

EDIT: To add to Gary's comment - the reason why I think an asymptotic is possible for $Q \equiv 1$ say and $R(t, \kappa) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} t^{j}R_{j}(\kappa)$ for $R_j$ polynomials of order $m_j$ say is because the top order term is $t^n$ and integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty t^{m-1}e^{-t^n}dt$ which reminds me of the moments of the Weibull distribution - it might be a bit naïve but I'm thinking that for fixed $\kappa$ we can control the polynomial in some sense. (This I'm not so sure.)

Comment: I belive your problem is way to general to have a reasonable answer. The asymptotics will highly depend on the way $P(t,\kappa)$ depends on $\kappa$.

Comment: Can you give an example? Let me fix for instance $Q(\kappa) \equiv 1$ so that the polynomial $P(t, \kappa)$ is $t^n + t^{n-1}R_{n-1}(\kappa) + t^{n-2}R_{n-2}(\kappa) + \cdots$, i.e. it's $t^n$ plus lower order terms where the coefficients are polynomials in $\kappa$. The idea I've got is that as $\kappa$ gets large, the polynomials $R_{j}(\kappa)$ roughly behave like the largest order term, say $\kappa^{m(j)}$ where the order $m(j)$ depends on $j$. Will this help simplify things?

Comment: After a substitution $t=\kappa^\alpha s$ with a suitable $\alpha>0$ you may use Theorem 2.1 (page 326), Theorem 4.1 (page 332) or Exercise 4.1 (page 333) in F. W. J. Olver's book *Asymptotics and Special Functions*.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{extpfeil}$
**Not a full answer**
well, i believe a simple general answer to your problem probably doesn't exist.
**About $L$**
in general, you can simplify a problem involving a non zero $L$ into one involving a zero $L$ in the following way:
$$\int_L^\infty t^{Q-1} e^{-P(t, \kappa)}dt \xrightarrow{u=t-L}\int_0^\infty {(u+L)}^{Q-1} e^{-P(u+L, \kappa)}du=\int_0^\infty {(u+L)}^{Q-1} e^{-P(u+L, \kappa)}du =\int_0^\infty \left(\sum^{Q-1}_{k=0}\binom{Q-1}{k}u^kL^{Q-k-1}\right) e^{-P(u+L, \kappa)}du=\sum^{Q-1}_{k=0}\binom{Q-1}{k}L^{Q-k-1}\int_0^\infty u^k e^{-P(u+L, \kappa)}du$$
**Special case**
$P(t,\kappa)=P(t)+P(\kappa)$
$$\int_L^\infty t^{Q-1} e^{-P(t, \kappa)}dt=\int_L^\infty t^{Q-1} e^{-P(t)-P(\kappa)}dt=e^{-P(\kappa)}\overbrace{\int_L^\infty t^{Q-1} e^{-P(t)}dt}^{\text{constant(Assuming convergence)}}$$